# Training tesseract to use with iPhone

Tags: iphone, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use tesseract-2.04 in my iPhone application and just want to detect the numbers. What I am doing here is first I am cross compiling tesseract to generate lib file using this post http://robertcarlsen.net/2009/07/15/cross-compiling-for-iphone-dev-884 and then using the the demo application at http://robertcarlsen.net/2010/01/12/ocr-for-iphone-source-1080 , but the results far away than realistic.

I am not able to resolve the issue or how to train tesseract so that it comes closure for practical usage.

Please help.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: Is there a specific set of numbers you are trying to recognize? Like a specific font? or just generic "recognize numbers".

Comment: @christophercotton The app recognizes a specific font very well, I just want to make the app able to understand more fonts and for that I need to add fonts, I am not able to figure out how I should add these fonts and the format of the fonts.

Comment: There is a pretty detailed version of how to train tesseract, though I've not gone through the process so I'm not making an answer. It seems quite involved http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract  Have you looked through there on how to generate new training characters?

Comment: If you don't mind calling an external web API for OCR instead of using Tesseract, there's an API that is specifically optimized for mobile device cameras / low-quality images: The WiseTrend OCR API ( http://www.wisetrend.com/wisetrend_ocr_cloud.shtml , sign up at http://www.webservius.com/cons/subscribe.aspx?p=wisetrend&s=wiseocr ) - it's based on the ABBYY engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get quite good results setting

```
TessBaseAPI::SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
```

while gently urging the user to let the numbers fit in a certain box. This makes locating the numbers easier for me, and ensures the user keeps the image steady and at a reasonable distance leading to a sharper image.

I have thought about altering valid_word() in tesseract-2.04/dict/permute.cpp, but there seems to be no need for that.

The next step will be to hardcode a minimum/maximum char size so recognition time can become way less than the 500 ms it is now. Then the next step will be to add some code that keeps track of results in time, so that reading `5` 90% of the time and `8` only 10% will lead the code to remember the `5`.

It all depends on the use case you have. I'm lucky in the sense that I'm allowed to just show a 200x50 box which will contain the number.

Comment: Good answer +1 for it. Can you tell me from where you got this idea or the place where these kind of things are documented

Comment: The whitelisting is documented (somewhere, google is your friend) and the other things are my plans, while waiting if the project will get a *go*.