# How can I recognize handwritten numbers within an image in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, ocr

I'm trying to develop an iOS app that allows the user to take a photograph of a handwritten phone number. Is there any library available that will allow me to extract the numerical values from the handwriting in this picture?

Comment: You need some OCR technology. Try googling OCR...

Comment: @all: The question has been voted down... quite un-deservedly. rao obviously is a newbie member, and he's not a native speaker, but this treatment of him is very, very unfriendly. He just asked for an OCR library that recognizes handwriting (numbers only).

Comment: I link to some resources that might be of use in this question: [Is number recognition on iPhone possible in real-time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887313/is-number-recognition-on-iphone-possible-in-real-time)

Comment: Check my answer [Are there any handwriting recognition libraries available for the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607827/are-there-any-handwriting-recognition-libraries-available-for-the-iphone/15950567#15950567)

Comment: 1 vote up for him (y)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to use OCR to recognize the text from the image. One of the most popular open0source libraries used for iOS OCR is a Google-sponsored open source project called [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).

Here's how to compile OCR for iOS:

http://robertcarlsen.net/2010/09/24/compiling-tesseract-v3-for-iphone-1299

After you get the text, do this to call the number:

```
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumberFromOCR];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString]]];
```

I would put the above code in an IBAction connected to a button maybe called "Call", so when the user presses the "Call" button, this code is called and the number recognized from the image is called.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try OpenCV and tesseract-ocr. Good luck, you've got your work cut out for you.

```
http://opencv.org/
https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/
```